# Pass a parameter from Express router to React before compiling through webpack and rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, reactjs, routes

My project is configured in `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports={
    context: __dirname+'/src',
    entry:'./main.js',
    output:{
        path:__dirname+'/static',
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
        {
            test:/\.png$/,
            loader:'url?limit=10000'
        },
        {
            test:/\.jpg$/,
            loader:'url?limit=10000'
        },
        {
            test:/\.css$/,
            loader:'style!css'
        },
        {  
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

In server of Express, I wrote a router like this:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.render('index');
    });
```

This is logic from my `main.js` to render for client:

```
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
var Content=require('./index').Content;
var style=require('../public/css/style.css');
var google=require('../public/images/btn_sign_in_google.png');

var Main=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="page-content">
                    <div id="header" className="homepage">
                        <h3 className="main-logo">Corate</h3>
                        <a href="/auth/google" className="google-login-logo"><img src={google}/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <Content className="homepage-content">
                    </Content>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main style={style}/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is `index` file, which will be sent by Express router to respond client's request, written in Jade template engine:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charget='utf-8')
    title Corate
    script(type='text/javascript', src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
  body
    #app
    script(type='text/javascript', src='bundle.js')
```

I bundled with webpack. Now I want to pass some parameters from router / middleware of Express to my `main.js` file for it to conduct logic from sent information (such as database, session...), before bundling with webpack and responding and rendering for client according to those passed parameters. It's not like pass parameter from router to template, this is to pass from router to the logic which bundles and renders that template. I've been stuck at this all day. Please help me